How can I check if a cookie existis in client-side with Astro?
I'm trying to display a cookies banner if user didn't accept it yet using <script>. So, how can I access Astro.cookies.has() on client-side?
My current code is something like this (also using tailwind):
if (!userAcceptsCookies && !sessionStorage.getItem("cookies-denied")) {
    cookiesConsentBanner?.classList.remove("hidden");
  }


You can read the cookie in client-side javascript only if it's not a HttpOnly cookie. If it's not, you can use document.cookie, e.g.:
const getCookies = () =>
  document.cookie.split(";")
    .map(str => str.trim().split(/=(.+)/))
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc[curr[0]] = curr[1];
        return acc;
    }, {})

const userAcceptsCookies = !!getCookies()['nameOfYourCookie']


Alternatively, in Astro componeents, you can pass the info from the server to your client-side script like this:
---
const userCookie = !!Astro.cookies.get('nameOfYourCookie')
---

<script data-userCookie={userCookie}>
  const userAcceptsCookies = !!document.currentScript.dataset.userCookie
</script>


@wlnyyyy I updated my answer with an alternative solution. feel free to upvote :)
